How to convert IFormFile to IBrowserFile or vice versa?
My Blazor application has both UI and API endpoints, I am trying to write a common method for handling user uploaded files, Methoed accepts the file and converts and returns the content as string.
The problem is that API endpoint takes IFormFile whereas the UI takes IBrowserFile, I am not able to convert them to a common type in order to write a generic method.

when you send the form the  will be sent (streamed) as IFormFile.  IBrowserFile is a local reference to the file the user chose.  (usually used for things like previewing the file to be sent) If you are not sending the form, just use the string, but you'll lose some efficiency there.  If sending via JS, you can send the whole form by creating a FormData() object from the form.

@browsermator Hey not sure if I understand, all I trying to do is convert them to a common type, Thanks

that can't really be done as one is a reference to a local client-side file, and the other is a bound type for incoming data.  (one's purely client-side, and the other's purely server-side)

No converting IFormFile to IBrowserFile, a sample you could handle such issue with file stream.
FileConverter.cs
public static class FileConverter
{
    public static async Task<string> ConvertFileToStringAsync(Stream fileStream)
    {
        var converter = new StreamReader(fileStream);
        return await converter.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
}

API Endpoint
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class FileUploadController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("upload")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file)
    {
        //Custom Validation
        //...

        var stream = file.OpenReadStream();
        string content = await FileConverter.ConvertFileToStringAsync(stream);

        return Ok("Success");
    }
}

Razor component
@page "/fileupload"
@inject IJSRuntime JS
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms

<InputFile OnChange="UploadFile" />

@code {
    private async Task UploadFile(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        IBrowserFile file = e.File;

        //Custom Validation
        //...

        var stream = file.OpenReadStream();
        string content = await FileConverter.ConvertFileToStringAsync(stream);
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("console.log", content);
    }
}



